# Boost::Asio Chat Server-Client Failure

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have compiled and run the chat server example from boost::asio, but am having some issues with it.  The client can connect to the server without issue, but whenever text is entered, it is not sent to the server.  Perhaps 1 in 10 messages will be detected by the server, except no data is actually received.

Any ideas?  I've copied the code verbatim (with a few exceptions to renaming, and I have only one server).

Comment: please post your code, specifically what you have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug the code: e.g. you could put breakpoints in the various handlers on the client. In order to do this it would be helpful if you understand the asynchronous flow of the code though i.e. on the client `handle_connect` will be the first asynchronous handler to be called, etc.

Stepping through `handle_connect` on the client will tell you whether the socket is successfully connected. Similarly `handle_write` will tell you the result of the asynchronous write operation.

Again, similarly, `handle_accept` on the server will be invoked once the client has connected.

Alternately, add `printf`s to the asio code to see what is being executed and what is not.

P.S. I'm assuming you do hit enter to send a message from the client?